# Mediaplayer - All songs are playing at the same time - Other song is not getting stopped

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, audio-player, android-music-player

I am trying to play music ( from url /server) in my app.I listed 2 songs there. Everything is working fine. Except one problem. All songs are playing at the same time...I want to play one song only a time. I repeat all songs are playing simultaneously .

Here is a screenshot of that app

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<SongInfo> _songs = new ArrayList<SongInfo>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    SongAdapter songAdapter;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);


        SongInfo s = new SongInfo("Cheap Thrills", "sia", "http://176.126.236.250/33Mmt/music/hindi/movies/new/oh_my_god/Go-Go-Govinda_(webmusic.in).mp3");
        _songs.add(s);

        s = new SongInfo("Cheap Thrills", "sia", "http://176.126.236.250/33Mmt/music/hindi/movies/new/oh_my_god/Go-Go-Govinda_(webmusic.in).mp3");
        _songs.add(s);

        songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, _songs);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
                linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter);


        songAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new SongAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final Button b, View view, SongInfo obj, int position) {
                try {
                    if (b.getText().toString().equals("stop")) {
                        b.setText("Play");
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        mediaPlayer = null;
                    }else {
                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(obj.getSongUrl());
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.start();
                                b.setText("stop");
                            }
                        });
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

this is my song adapter code -:

```
package com.a03.dip.kaliprasadbengalisongs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SongAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongAdapter.SongHolder> {

    ArrayList<SongInfo> _songs;
    Context context;

    OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    SongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SongInfo> songs) {
        this.context = context;
        this._songs = songs;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Button b ,View view, SongInfo obj, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public SongHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_song,viewGroup,false);
        return new SongHolder(myView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SongHolder songHolder, final int i) {
        final SongInfo c = _songs.get(i);
        songHolder.songName.setText(_songs.get(i).songName());
        songHolder.artistName.setText(_songs.get(i).artistName());
        songHolder.btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(songHolder.btnAction,v, c, i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return _songs.size();
    }

    public class SongHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView songName,artistName;
        Button btnAction;

        public SongHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            songName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongName);
            artistName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvArtistName);
            btnAction = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

        }
    }
}
```

and here is songInfo class -----

```
package com.a03.dip.kaliprasadbengalisongs;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class SongInfo {
        public String songName ,artistName,songUrl;

    public SongInfo() {
    }

    public SongInfo(String songName, String artistName, String songUrl) {
        this.songName = songName;
        this.artistName = artistName;
        this.songUrl = songUrl;
    }

    public String songName() {
        return songName;
    }

    public String artistName() {
        return artistName;
    }

    public String getSongUrl() {
        return songUrl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! This is my question ,still i want to answer this question. After doing Lots of research I found the solution, and I think I should share it  through the answer.

So , the first thing you have to do is that....

1. Delete all codes in main - activity which you have added. Also , don't forget to delete other 2 classes ( songadapter and songInfo)
2. Now add this simple code to play audio from url...

   public class PlayaudioActivity extends Activity {

   ```
   private MediaPlayer mp;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

       b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               stopPlaying();
              mp.setDataSource("http://q.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/9/10183_1367780535.mp3");
             // mediaPlayer.prepare();
               mp.start();


   if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
           bPlay.setText(“Stop”);
           mediaPlayer.pause();
       }
       else {
           bPlay.setText(“Stop”);
           mediaPlayer.start();
       }

           }

       });
   ```

By this way you can add more song and play them without having any problems. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in MainActivity2.java. Then code will work fine...

```
private Button PREVIOUS_SONG = null;
```

add this code inside

```
songAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new SongAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final Button b, View view, SongInfo obj, int position) {
                try {

    if(PREVIOUS_SONG==null){
                    PREVIOUS_SONG=b;


                }
                else{
                    if(b!=PREVIOUS_SONG){
                        PREVIOUS_SONG.setText("Play");
                        PREVIOUS_SONG=b;
                    }
                }
                    if (b.getText().toString().equals("stop")) {
                        if(mediaPlayer!=null)
                {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                    b.setText("Play");

                    tvstartTime.setText("00:00");
                    tvEndTime.setText("00:00");}
            }else {

                if(mediaPlayer!=null)
                {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;


                    tvstartTime.setText("00:00");
                    tvEndTime.setText("00:00");}
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(obj.getSongUrl());
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.start();
                                b.setText("stop");
                            }
                        });
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        });
```